# Delegando sub domínio Bind9 para AWS Route53

Tags: amazon-aws, bind

Olá, tenho um servidor Bind9 devidamente configurado e gostaria de configurá-lo para delegar um subdomínio para o serviço Route53 da AWS.

Por exemplo. Meu domínio configurado no Bing9 é example.org
Eu gostaria que o subdomínio testing.example.org seja configurado no serviço AWS Route53 para que todos os registros dentro desse subdomínio sejam configurados no Route53 pois esse serviço oferece algumas políticas de roteamento que serão úteis para meu ambiente (Failover principalmente).

Realizei algumas pesquisas e até o momento não encontrei uma solução.
Desde já agradeço a ajuda de todos.

Answer (score 1):

Encontrei a solução.

Na configuração da zona example.org no Bind9 insira os registros do tipo NS apontando para os Name Servers que a AWS fornece quando criamos uma nova zona.
`testing    IN  NS    ns-1493.awsdns-38.org.
testing    IN  NS    ns-743.awsdns-34.net.
testing    IN  NS    ns-1851.awsdns-16.co.uk.
testing    IN  NS    ns-191.awsdns-19.com.`

A partir desse momento, todos os registros que você deseja configurar dentro desse sub domínio basta configurá-los no Route53.